# Grails URL mapping that includes id

Tags: url, grails

Is it possible to add a URL mapping that includes controller/action/id? Example:

URL:
 
localhost:8080/myproject/book/scifi/dune
localhost:8080/myproject/book/scifi/walking+dead

new URL: 
localhost:8080/myproject/dune
localhost:8080/myproject/walking_dead

I tried:

```
static mappings = {
   "/books" (controller: "book", action: "scifi", id: "dune")
   "/walking_dead" (controller: "book", action: "scifi", id: "walking+dead")
}
```

Doesn't seem to work. Basically our client want specific URLS, I was using ids, then changed it to names as the ids. But now the client wants unique URLs. THanks for any help or insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static mappings = {
  "/$bookId" (controller: "book", action: "scifi")
}
```

and the value is available as params.bookId in the controller